# How to setup NVIC for DMA in STM32CubeMX?

Tags: dma, stm32cubemx

I am trying to connect STM32G070 microcontroller with Quectel BC660K-GL via UART in DMA mode. I am using STM32CubeMX for programming. I understand basic principles how DMA works, therefore settings inside the **DMA Settings** tag are quite clear to me, but I don't understand the **NVIC Settings** tag, namely, should I check or uncheck *USART1 global interrupt / USART1 wake-up interrupt through EXTI line 25* (shown in figure 1):
[Fig.1: NVIC Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqlwl.png)
There is a bunch of tutorials online but I can't find more information about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use DMA for UART communication, then it is DMA and UART, who talk to each other and decide when to load/store next byte of data. USART interrupts are needed if you want to have an interrupt handler for UART for when some USART event occurs, such as byte received or frame error or transmission complete or other. But if you want DMA to handle the communication, USART and DMA can do it between themselves without your intervention. Interrupts are, in fact, not required at all for DMA to function. It will know when to load/store new piece of data without any interrupts. Therefore, USART interrupts would be unnecessary.

Normally, it is only DMA interrupts you would be interested in. Since DMA took over control over sending/receiving data, it is DMA flags that will require your attention - transfer complete or transfer error, for example. Unless **you** have some specific reason to react to some USART event, you don't need USART interrupts, and neither does DMA.

Comment: I am using HAL libraries. If I understood you well mister @Ilya, when USART interrupt is **not** enabled, function `HAL_UART_IRQHandler()` and corresponding callback functions for setting HT and TC flags (*Half-Transfer completed* and *Transfer Completed*, respectively, e.g. `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()`) are **not** called, but functions `XferCpltCallback()`, `XferHalfCpltCallback` (defined in struct `DMA_HandleTypeDef()`) are called?

Comment: Yes, USART interrupt handler will not be called - and DMA doesn't need it to function. If DMA interrupts are enabled, DMA interrupt handler functions will be called. If those DMA callbacks utilize DMA interrupts to be triggered (and it seems they do by the logic of what they are), then yes, your statement must be correct.